# How would I include the inequalities in this optimization?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm using scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize the drag on the wings of an airplane based on 18 total equations. I have 10 constraints as well on the 18 variables. When I run the code, I get the error message

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

I'm thinking this is because the size of the constraints array and the size of the variable array are different; however, I'm not sure the best way to include the constraints on existing variables using something similar.

```
from __future__ import division
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
os.system('clear')

S = 6
W = 10
rho = 0.0023769                                                                                
mu = 3.38*10**(-7)

def func(x):
    """ Drag function to minimize """
    return (1/2)*rho*x[1]**2*x[12]*x[3]


def func_deriv(x):

    dDdv = rho*x[1]*x[12]*x[3]
    dDdCD = (1/2)*rho*x[1]**2*x[3]
    dDdS = (1/2)*rho*x[1]**2*x[12]
    return np.array([ dDdv, dDdCD, dDdS ])


# Put the constraints here
cons = ({'type': 'eq', # Calculates the required lift coefficient, CL [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[0] - 2*W/(rho*x[1]**2*x[3])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([1,(4*W)/(rho*x[1]**3*x[3]),0,(2*W)/(rho*x[1]**2*x[3]**2),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates FAA ground speed, vFAA [ft/s]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[1] - x[2]*np.cos(x[13])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,1,-np.cos(x[13]),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x[2]*np.sin(x[13]),0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the span, b [ft]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[4] - x[3]/((1+x[14])*x[5])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,-1/((1+x[14])*x[5]),1,x[3]/((1+x[14])*x[5]**2),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x[3]/((1+x[14])**2*x[5]),0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the tip chord, ct [ft]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[6] - x[14]*x[5]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,-x[14],1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-x[5],0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the Reynolds Number, Re [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[7] - (rho*x[1]*x[6])/mu]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,-(rho*x[6])/mu,0,0,0,0,-(rho*x[1])/mu,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the FAA wing area, S [ft^2]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[3] - 1838*W/(x[2]**2)]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,3676*W/x[3]**3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the induced drag coefficient, CDi [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[10] - x[0]**2/(np.pi*x[9]*x[8])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([(-2*x[0])/(np.pi*x[9]*x[8]),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x[0]**2/(np.pi*x[9]*x[8]**2),x[0]**2/(np.pi*x[9]**2*x[8]),1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the parasitic drag coefficient, CDo [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[10] - x[11]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the aspect ratio, [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[9] - x[4]**2 / x[3]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,x[4]**2/x[3]**2,-2*x[4] / x[3],0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the total drag coefficient, CDt [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[12] - x[10] - x[11]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq',
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[1] - (4/(np.pi*x[9]*x[8]*x[11]))**(1/4)*np.sqrt((W/x[5])/rho)]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,1,0,0,0, \
                                 (-W*(1/(x[9]*x[8]*x[11])))/(np.sqrt(2)*np.pi**(1/4)*rho*x[5]**2*np.sqrt(W/(rho*x[5]))), \
                                 0,0, \
                                 -np.sqrt(W/(rho*x[5]))/(2*np.sqrt(2)*np.pi**(1/4)*x[9]*x[8]**2*x[11]*(1/x[9]*x[8]*x[11])**(3/4)), \
                                 -np.sqrt(W/(rho*x[5]))/(2*np.sqrt(2)*np.pi**(1/4)*x[8]*x[9]**2*x[11]*(1/x[9]*x[8]*x[11])**(3/4)),
                                 0, \
                                 -np.sqrt(W/(rho*x[5]))/(2*np.sqrt(2)*np.pi**(1/4)*x[9]*x[11]**2*x[8]*(1/x[9]*x[8]*x[11])**(3/4)), \
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the quarter chord sweep angle [rad]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[17] - np.arctan((.25*(x[6]-x[5]) + x[4]*np.tan(x[13]))/x[4])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,\
                                 -((np.tan(x[13])/x[4])-(x[4]*np.tan(x[13])+0.25*(x[6]-x[5]))/(x[4]**2))/((x[4]*np.tan(x[13])+0.25*(x[6]-x[5]))**2/(x[4]**2)+1), \
                                 0.25/(x[4]*((x[4]*np.tan(x[13])+0.25*(x[6]-x[5]))**2/(x[4]**2)+1)), \
                                 -0.25/(x[4]*((x[4]*np.tan(x[13])+0.25*(x[6]-x[5]))**2/(x[4]**2)+1)), \
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0,\
                                 -(1/np.cos(x[13]))/((x[4]*np.tan(x[13])+0.25*(x[6]-x[5]))**2/(x[4]**2)+1), \
                                 0,0,0,1])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the change in taper ratio [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[15] + 0.357 - 0.45*np.exp(0.0375*x[17])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,-0.016875*np.exp(0.0375*x[17])])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the Nita function for e
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[16] - 0.0524*(x[14]-x[15])**4 - 0.1500*(x[14]-x[15])**3 + 0.1659*(x[14]-x[15])**2 - 0.0706*(x[14]-x[15]) + 0.0119]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, \
                                 0.2096*(x[14]-x[15])**3 - 0.45*(x[14]-x[15])**2 + 0.3318*(x[14]-x[15]) - 0.0706, \
                                 -0.2096*(x[14]-x[15])**3 + 0.45*(x[14]-x[15])**2 - 0.3318*(x[14]-x[15]) + 0.0706,
                                 1,0])},
    {'type': 'eq', # Calculates the Oswald efficiency factor, e [-]
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[8] - 1/(1+x[16]*x[9])]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1/(1+x[16]*x[9]**2), \
     0,0,0,0,0,0,1/(1+x[16]**2*x[9]),0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that sweep > 0
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[14]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that sweep < 1.1
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([np.pi/4 - x[0]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that CL > 0
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[0]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that CL < 1.1
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([1.1 - x[0]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that tr > 0.2
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[14] - 0.2]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that tr < 1
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([1 - x[14]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures that ground speed > 25 kts
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[2] - 42.2]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures tha A > 4
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[9] - 4]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type':'ineq', # Ensures tha A < 20
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([20 - x[9]]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])},
    {'type': 'ineq', # Set Re > 100k to avoid Reynold's drag
     'fun' : lambda x: np.array([x[7]-100000]),
     'jac' : lambda x: np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])})


res = minimize(func, [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], args=(), jac=func_deriv,
           constraints=cons, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})


print res.x
```

I'm newer to coding, so this might be completely wrong, but I'm pretty sure that it's close.

Comment: In objective function you use only 3 parameters: x[1], x[12], x[3], in constraints 17, in initial conditions 18. If you expect some effect from constraints  you should use the same parameters in objective function and constraints. Try to make it work at least without constraints , and then add one by one.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov thank you! Would I have to use simultaneous equations in func, and then just use the inequalities as bounds for optimization?